# iPhone: How to change the color of an image

Tags: iphone, colors, cgimage

I have a small image from a database and the image's average color need to be altered slightly.

It's a *CGImageRef* and I thought of creating a *CGContext*, drawing the image to this context, then subsequently changing the bitmap data somehow and finally rendering it.
But how can I alter the color information?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this Apple Q&A on pixel data manipulation](http://developer.apple.com/qa/qa2007/qa1509.html) for details on how you might go about that.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a color onto the object like this:

```
    // first draw image
    [self.image drawInRect:rect];

    // prepare the context to draw into
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // set the blend mode and draw rectangle on top of image
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeColor);
    CGContextClipToMask(context, self.bounds, image.CGImage); // this restricts drawing to within alpha channel
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.75, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // this is your color,  a light reddish tint
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
```

I put this into the drawRect: method of a custom UIView. That UIView has an ivar, UIImage *image that holds the image you want to tint or color.

Comment: Thanks, but I needed to change every pixel for its own.