# How do I apply a sepia tone to a photo with on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How do I apply a sepia tone to a photo with Cocoa Touch on the iPhone?

Comment: These questions are similar to yours and might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341716/iphone-how-to-change-the-color-of-an-image and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117211/how-would-i-tint-an-image-programatically-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to work with the CGImage property of your UIImage.
Then, take a look at the reference of the [CGImageRef](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html) type to learn how you can manipulate single pixels.

Comment: You can't learn how to manipulate single pixels in the CGImage reference. You need a CGBitmapContext.